# Java: Trying to read object with objectoutputstream/objectinputstream - crashes

Tags: java, objectoutputstream, objectinputstream

On my server class I am writing a 2D char array out through an ObjectOutputStream and the client reads this with an ObjectInputStream.  Afterwards I try to send another 2D array through the same `ObjectOutputStream` to the same `ObjectInputStream` but the program crashes. I guess my newline is left within the `ObjectOutputStream` but I am unsure of how to get rid of that.  I tried `inFromServ.read()`, `inFromServ.readLine()`, `inFromServ.flush()`.  None of which fixed the problem =/.  Any help would be appreciated!

Client code:

```
ObjectInputStream inFromServ = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
printBoard((char[][])inFromServ.readObject()); //Prints the first 2D char array fine

System.out.println(inFromServ.readObject()); //Reads in a string fine
System.out.println(inFromServ.readObject()); //Reads in another string fine

System.out.println("Your shots board:"); //Writes this out fine
printBoard((char[][])inFromServ.readObject()); //Crashes here
```

Server code:

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clients[0].getInputStream());
ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(clients[0].getOutputStream());
char p1brd[][]=new char[10][10];
char p1shots[][]=new char[10][10];

out.writeObject(p1brd); //Writes out the first board fine
out.writeObject("some string"); //Writes this string fine
out.writeObject("some more string"); //Writes this string fine
out.writeObject(p1shots); //Don't even think it gets here... If i put a thread.sleep(10000) before this line it still crashes instantaneously after writing "some more string"
```

The client side is within a while(true) loop.  Once the printBoard((char[][])inFromServ.readObject()); is called for the second time my try/catch gets a hold of it and spews out the catch statement over and over until I stop the program.

Comment: *How* does it crash? I assume there's an exception? Do both the client *and* the server crash? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and edit your question with more information.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't 'crash' at all, it *throws* an *exception,* and you have a bug in your logic whereby you don't abandon reading when you've got an exception. Any exception reading from a socket other than `SocketTimeoutException` is fatal and the only proper response is to close the socket; stop reading it; and abandon the client.

Next time you report a 'crash' please provide the actual exception and stack trace.